# Insert Gzip response into json object

Tags: javascript, php

I'm building a simple proxy with php for server side and javascript for the client side (browser).
the php server receives post requests with json data , something like that:

```
{headersArray: ["Get /someurl...","Cookie: some cookie"],url...}
```

than after extracting the headers and the url the php code uses curl to fetch the resource , and at this point i would like to construct a response object on the client via the "`Response`" constructor , so i need to transmit back to the client the headers also so i thought about constructing again a json object which will contain the headers and the response body , but a lot of servers uses gzip encoding, can i insert the gzip encoded response body as a json property and safely transmit it back to the client? would i need to decode it on the client browser? does it add a lot of overhead? any better ideas?

Comment: what you are trying to create will result in something completely incompatible... a) gzip the whole JSON response and b) HTTP headers simply don't belong into the body

Comment: @MartinZeitler i'm getting an already gzipped response from the curl request on the php server and i would like to transmit it to the client with all the response headers also , so if i can't insert the response body to a json object and send it back what can i do?

Comment: you have to send out the HTTP headers (which might not be exactly the same) and then the JSON in the body, using a server which has gzip enabled for MIME type `application/json`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler  but how can I insert the gzip response to the json object?

Comment: this is meshuggah ...because no client could handle that trashed response. it needs to be gzipped by the server in one piece, so that the client can unpack it in one piece (this all happens automatically, when having gzip compression  enabled).

Comment: this question is just alike "how to insert a `zip` file into a text file?" ...